# How can I have text show on screen after modal box closes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a modal box. Within the modal box there is a text that is colored blue. The text is called Publication and it is linked to my checkbox. The user would interact with the text and whey they did it would go from blue to red. When the text was red it would mean the checkbox is checked.

Now the problem is I want the text shown when the text publication is red, to only show once the user has clicked apply.

Currently, I have tried using .prop but the entire code then collapses and nothing ends up working.

Please can someone show me a working solution.

```html
    <head>
    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- jQuery Modal -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    
    </head>
    
    <style> 
    
    .onlyThese{
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
     user-select: none;           
    }
 
    input[type="checkbox"]+label {  color:blue } 
    
    input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 
    }
    
    input:focus{
        outline: none;   
    }
 
        </style>
     
    <p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> </p>
    <div id="ex5"; class="modal"; style="background-color:white">
    <div style="float:left;">
    
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" > <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label> </p>
    
    <div id="myDiv">the preparation and issuing of a book, journal, or piece of music for public sale.</div>
    </div>
        
    <div>
    <p style="float:right"> 
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close"; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a> 
    </p>    
    </div>
    
    </div>

        <script>
        
      $('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(this).modal({
            escapeClose: false,
            clickClose: false,
            showClose: false,
          });
        });
     
     $('.yourCheckbox').change(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $('#myDiv').show();
      } else {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
      }
    });
 </script>
```

The expected output is as follows:

- User clicks on the modal box named "sectors"
- User then interacts with the text colored blue named "publication"
- User clicks on said text and it has turned red which in turn has checked the checkbox
- User clicks apply to close modal box and the information contained in the div is displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to achieve. Run the Snippet to see the result.

```html
    <head>
    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- jQuery Modal -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    
    </head>
    
    <style> 
    
    .onlyThese{
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
     user-select: none;           
    }
 
    input[type="checkbox"]+label {  color:blue } 
    
    input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {  color:red } 
    }
    
    input:focus{
        outline: none;   
    }
 
        </style>
     
    <p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> </p>
    <div id="ex5"; class="modal"; style="background-color:white">
    <div style="float:left;">
    
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" > <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label> </p>
    
    <div id="myDiv">the preparation and issuing of a book, journal, or piece of music for public sale.</div>
    </div>
        
    <div>
    <p style="float:right"> 
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close"; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a> 
    </p>    
    </div>
    
    </div>

        <script>
        var content = "";
      $('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(this).modal({
            escapeClose: false,
            clickClose: false,
            showClose: false,
          });
        });
     
     $('.yourCheckbox').change(function(){
      if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $('#myDiv').show();
        content = $('#myDiv').html();
      } else {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
        content = "";
      }
    });
$('[rel="modal:close"]').on('click',()=>{
         $('.btn').parent().append(content);
        })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues going on.  First, an element can only have one ID.  You need to change the ID for your checkbox from `id="group1 yourCheckbox"` to `id="group1"` and make "yourCheckbox" a class or something else.  If you make it a class, then you'll need to change your JS from `$('#yourCheckbox').change` to `$('.yourCheckbox').change`.

That should get you a good head start.  Also, consider using the JS to add/remove a class instead of the old `.show() / .hide()` method.  You'll have more control over the way things look because you can use CSS to do the work.

Getting the div to stay on the page after the modal is closed requires a bit more code for when the "Apply" button is pressed.  You'll need an `.on( 'click', function()` event to fire.  Or consider using the modal's callback functionality for when that button is clicked.

Comment: How would I apply a better alternative than .show() and .hide()

Comment: Well, Trikoninfosystems took everything I said, but actually wrote the code for you, so they get all the credit!!!  Goodness... instead of `.show()/.hide()`, use `.addClass( 'showme' )/.removeClass( 'showme' )`.  Then you can use `.showme { display: block; }` or whatever... even add a transition so it fades in/out or whatever you want.